# Consulta sql (mysql) y timestamp

Tags: mysql

quiero consultar los resultados en un rango de fechas y realizar joins. Actualmente mi query es:

```
SELECT  fichapagos.cantidad, 
users.name as nombreRecibe, 
modopagos.nombre as tipoDePago, 
clientes.nombre as elCliente,
conceptopagos.concepto as elConcepto
FROM fichapagos, users,modopagos,clientes,conceptopagos 

WHERE MONTH(fichapagos.created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) 
AND YEAR(fichapagos.created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())

LEFT JOIN modopagos  
ON fichapagos.tipoPago = modopagos.id 
LEFT JOIN clientes
ON fichapagos.organizacionPara = clientes.id
LEFT JOIN conceptopagos
ON fichapagos.conceptoPago = conceptopagos.id
LEFT JOIN users
on fichapagos.nombreRecibe = users.id
```

Pero me bota error:

```
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'LEFT JOIN modopagos ON fichapagos.tipoPago = modopagos.id LEFT JOIN cliente' en la linea 11
```

El campo created_at es tipo timestamp, si no tengo los joins la consulta funciona. Si no tengo WHERE la consulta funciona. ¿qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando tu query tienes los siguientes inconvenientes:

1. El uso del **WHERE** debe ser después de las relaciones, en este caso de tus **LEFT JOINS**.
2. En el **FROM** debes indicar una sola tabla, y por recomendación y buenas prácticas, deberías partir de la tabla con mayor cantidad de registros.

Con ello tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT fichapagos.cantidad, 
    users.name as nombreRecibe, 
    modopagos.nombre as tipoDePago, 
    clientes.nombre as elCliente,
    conceptopagos.concepto as elConcepto
FROM fichapagos  --  Tabla según yo, más extensa.
LEFT JOIN modopagos  
    ON fichapagos.tipoPago = modopagos.id 
LEFT JOIN clientes
    ON fichapagos.organizacionPara = clientes.id
LEFT JOIN conceptopagos
    ON fichapagos.conceptoPago = conceptopagos.id
LEFT JOIN users
    on fichapagos.nombreRecibe = users.id
WHERE MONTH(fichapagos.created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())  --  Cambio de ubicación.
    AND YEAR(fichapagos.created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Pruebalo y cuentanos. Saludos.

Comment: El punto 2 no es que *deba*, no es obligatorio. Se pueden usar *joins implícitos*, que es lo que él intenta hacer. Aunque coincido contigo en que es más claro como indicas en tu respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación y la corrección, funciona como deseaba

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta sentencia:

```
SELECT  fichapagos.cantidad, 
users.name as nombreRecibe, 
modopagos.nombre as tipoDePago, 
clientes.nombre as elCliente,
conceptopagos.concepto as elConcepto
FROM fichapagos, users,modopagos,clientes,conceptopagos 

LEFT JOIN modopagos  
ON fichapagos.tipoPago = modopagos.id 
LEFT JOIN clientes
ON fichapagos.organizacionPara = clientes.id
LEFT JOIN conceptopagos
ON fichapagos.conceptoPago = conceptopagos.id
LEFT JOIN users
on fichapagos.nombreRecibe = users.id

WHERE MONTH(fichapagos.created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) 
AND YEAR(fichapagos.created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

El `WHERE` lo usamos luego de los `LEFT JOIN`.